# Login to mt4 account by python script

Tags: python, mt4

I know integrating python with Metatrader5 isn't that hard, its relatively easy compared to python integration with mt4. But the Issue is I don't need the mt5 integration, I only need mt4 integration

I wanted to know if it's possible to login to mt4 account via python script (python 3.6 and above) where I enter the account number, password and server address in python script ,

doing this in mt5 is simple, but I cant seem to find a way to do it in mt4. Is it even possible for mt4 or am I just pushing it for no reason

Answer (score 1):

You would need to hop through MQL and a system-level dll implementation of some kind of messaging service warper. MQL can load a dll and you can expose functions from that dll in MQL: https://docs.mql4.com/basis/preprosessor/import

https://docs.mql4.com/runtime/imports

You would then post a login message to a topic, the dll will get the message(loop or callback), the MLQ script will pick up the request(loop or [ontimer](https://docs.mql4.com/basis/function/events)) and log you in.